# Kustomize - Merge multiple configMapGenerators

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, kustomize

So I'm dealing with a structure like this:

```
.
├── 1
│   ├── env-vars
│   └── kustomization.yaml
├── 2
│   ├── env-vars
│   └── kustomization.yaml
├── env-vars
├── kustomization.yaml
└── shared
    ├── env-vars
    └── kustomization.yaml
```

while env-vars within each level has some env vars and

```
$cat kustomization.yaml
bases:
- 1/
- 2/

namePrefix: toplevel-

configMapGenerator:
  - name: env-cm
    behavior: merge
    envs:
    - env-vars
```

```
$cat 1/kustomization.yaml
bases:
- ./../shared

namePrefix: first-

configMapGenerator:
  - name: env-cm
    behavior: merge
    envs:
    - env-vars
```

```
$cat 2/kustomization.yaml
bases:
- ./../shared

namePrefix: second-

configMapGenerator:
  - name: env-cm
    behavior: merge
    envs:
    - env-vars
```

```
$cat shared/kustomization.yaml
configMapGenerator:
  - name: env-cm
    behavior: create
    envs:
    - env-vars
```

I'm essentially trying to create 2 configmaps with some shared values (which are injected from different resources: from `shared` directory and the top-level directory)

---

`kustomize build .` fails with some conflict errors for finding multiple objects:

```
Error: merging from generator <blah>: found multiple objects <blah> that could accept merge of ~G_v1_ConfigMap|~X|env-cm
```

Unfortunately I need to use `merge` on the top-level `configMapGenerator`, since there are some labels injected to `1` and `2` configmaps (so `create`ing a top-level configmap altho addresses the env-vars, but excludes the labels)

Any suggestion on how to address this issue is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

I believe this should solve your issue.

`kustomization.yaml` which is located in `base` or `/`:

```
$ cat kustomization.yaml 
resources:
- ./1
- ./2

namePrefix: toplevel-

configMapGenerator:
  - name: first-env-cm
    behavior: merge
    envs:
    - env-vars
  - name: second-env-cm
    behavior: merge
    envs:
    - env-vars
```

With help of search I found [this github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/1442) which is I'd say the same issue. And then a pull-request with [changes in code](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/pull/1520/files#diff-c1e6b6a8ce9692d830228e40df4a604cf063ef54ca54e157f70981557e72f08bL606-R609). We can see that during `kustomize` render merge behaviour was changed to look for `currentId` instead of `originalId`. Knowing that we can address to exact "pre-rendered" configmaps separately.